# Is it possible to edit Cloud Functions via SSH on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, ide, google-cloud-functions

I know how to develop using Linux VMs and SSH on VS Code, but now I am using Cloud Functions and I would like to debug it on VS Code or any other editor/IDE, is it possible?

Comment: It's "serverelss", you can't ssh to the server! For testing, it's "problematic". I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-cloud-function-what-i-use-and-why-12bb5d3798e1). It's only my opinion, and a solution for testing your function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to debug the code that you are going to deploy into Cloud Functions in your favorite IDE. As the opposite to Compute Engine you can't ssh into Cloud Functions. Cloud Functions is based on preemptible Compute Engine instances, this means that you have no control at all over the instances and you can't ssh into them.

What you can actually do is develop your function as a small, idempotent piece of code, test it locally and then deploy it to Cloud Functions directly from your IDE, then if you want to see the logs of your function you can run the `gcloud functions logs` command directly on your ide